# What happens to MongoDB Database after updating Meteorjs app?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meteor, updates

I am thinking about taking a deeper look into Meteor.js. I've never worked with such a framework or MongoDB before. Let's say I have a Meteor.js app running and the DB is already filled with info. Now I want to update my App. Is the Database than replaced with a new one? Because as I can see Meteor has a built in MongoDB and I have no option to run the DB and the App seperatly right?

thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Meteor maintains the mongodb in `.meteor/local/db`. The database is run by the updated meteor or mongodb.

Recently in 1.0.4 they updated MongoDB from 2.4 to 2.6. This means your database created by < 1.0.4 on MongoDB 2.4 now runs MonoDB 2.6. This happens without trouble since you can use a 2.4 database by running it on 2.6.

I assume problems would occur if you downgrade your version of meteor or mongodb rather than update them since there is a mechanism in MongoDB to handle databases created on previous versions.

Keep in mind this is only in development mode (where you run your project using `meteor).

You can run the mongodb database/its required to in production mode where you create the bundle using `meteor build`. This also helps since you can maintain mongodb seperately in production mode and can have full control over any updates if you need to.

[1] http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/upgrade-revision/

Comment: thx for the comment but I guess you missunderstood my question :) I don't want to update the version of mongodb oder meteor. I asked what happend to the current DB if I update the app itself e.g. new content and stuff. Because in the updated files the "create new collection" line would still exist. Does it overwrite the previous collection with a new clean one or does everything stay as it was before?

Comment: @user3079933 I thought I mentioned that. To keep it short it stays as before/updates itself. You can't create collections in mongo they create themselves when you insert new documents in. So if you add content it stays as before albeit with the new content you add